# Unity - Depth texture is too pixelated

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics

I am trying to combine two cameras together: Background camera, Foreground camera.

I created 3 cameras in my project, 2 for the background and foreground and one for the foreground depth.

I then created a simple shader that combine the first two cameras (they render to render texture as well as the foreground depth), the problem I am having is that because the depth buffer is too pixelated the result looks funny and you clearly see the lines around the foreground (players in my case).

I created a depth camera with these properties:

[image: Camera properties Unity]

Notice the `Output Texture`, I have set the Render texture to:

[image: Depth render texture properties]

This is the result depth texture (zoomed so you can see the pixels):

[image]

Any idea how I can create that effect maybe using something different then the depth buffer? or can I improve the depth quality? what can I do to reach a good final result?

Comment: If you're using URP you can use [Camera Stacking](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.2/manual/camera-stacking.html).

Comment: @Iggy Currently, Camera Stacking doesn't support post processing effects on the Overlay camera, so it will not work for me

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, both cameras don't share post-processing effects, although you can still apply post-processing effects on the overlay camera.

Comment: The docs says you can't, I tried and it doesn't work, how would you do that? and all post processing (as the time of writing) are shared, there is a bug it seems.

Comment: Try changing `Environment > Volume Mask > Everything` on the overlay camera.

Comment: @Iggy As I said, the documentation says, no post processing on overlay camera..: `You cannot apply post-processing to an individual Overlay Camera. You can apply post-processing to an individual Base Camera, or to a Camera Stack.`